# Access object from db using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

hello i have this output using php

> [{"date":"2019-02-10","pleads":1},{"date":"2019-02-12","pleads":1},{"date":"2019-02-14","pleads":1}]

which i can easily access through this Jquery code

```
  // AJAX Request to get the data by UserID and Week 1
            $.get('/dashboard/performance?name=' + document.getElementById('agents').value + '&week=0', function(data){
                $.each(data,function(i,value){

                    var tr =$("<tr/>");
                    tr.append($("<th/>",{
                        text : value.date
                    })).append($("<th/>",{
                        text : value.pleads
                    }))
                    $('#tableData-performance-week1').append(tr);

                })
        });
```

but since i had to make some modifications to return more than one data from db now what php return is this

> {"adminleads":[{"date":"2019-02-02","aleads":1}],"managerleads":[{"date":"2019-02-01","mleads":1}],"personalleads":[{"date":"2019-02-02","pleads":2},{"date":"2019-02-03","pleads":1},{"date":"2019-02-04","pleads":1},{"date":"2019-02-05","pleads":1},{"date":"2019-02-06","pleads":1}]}

how can i access them through JQuery ? cuz i tried and i can't access them the normal way  Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) will work with an object as well in that case, the first argument would be property name and the second argument would be property value.

Now you have to iterate over the array(inner array, property value) use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method for that and within the loop check `plead` property is defined or not if defined then create and append the `tr`. For checking property defined or not you can use [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

```
 // iterate over all values
 $.each(data, function(k, arr) {
  // iterate over all objects within array
  arr.forEach(function(value) {
    // check pleads property defined if defined 
    // do the rest as you did early
    if ('pleads' in value) {

      var tr = $("<tr/>");
      tr.append($("<th/>", {
        text: value.date
      })).append($("<th/>", {
        text: value.pleads
      }))
      $('#tableData-performance-week1').append(tr);
    }
  });
})
```

```js
var data = {
  "adminleads": [{
    "date": "2019-02-02",
    "aleads": 1
  }],
  "managerleads": [{
    "date": "2019-02-01",
    "mleads": 1
  }],
  "personalleads": [{
    "date": "2019-02-02",
    "pleads": 2
  }, {
    "date": "2019-02-03",
    "pleads": 1
  }, {
    "date": "2019-02-04",
    "pleads": 1
  }, {
    "date": "2019-02-05",
    "pleads": 1
  }, {
    "date": "2019-02-06",
    "pleads": 1
  }]
}

$.each(data, function(k, arr) {
  arr.forEach(function(value) {
    if ('pleads' in value) {
      var tr = $("<tr/>");
      tr.append($("<th/>", {
        text: value.date
      })).append($("<th/>", {
        text: value.pleads
      }))
      $('#tableData-performance-week1').append(tr);
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableData-performance-week1"></table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer i got the exact same output as the code snippet but it's not what i wanted 
What i want is 
`2019-02-02 2
2019-02-03 1
2019-02-04 1
2019-02-05 1
2019-02-06 1`

Comment: @mohamedadel `2019-02-02 2
2019-02-03 1
2019-02-04 1
2019-02-05 1
2019-02-06 1`

Comment: it works but it gets pleads only i want to get aleads and mleads also to the table